# How to grep thousands of files in a directory for hundreds of strings in a file

Tags: grep

I am trying to compose a `grep` statement and it is killing me.  I am also tired of getting the `arguments list too long` error. I have a file, let's call it `subset.txt`. It contains hundreds of lines with specific strings such as `MO43312948`.  In my object directory I have thousands of files and I need to copy all the files that contain the strings listed in `subset.txt` into another directory.

I was trying to start with this to just return the matching files from the objects directory.

```
grep -F "$(subset.txt)" /objects/*
```

I keep getting `bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long``

Comment: Why have you put `"$(subset.txt)"` in the command like that?  That is [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), which will make your shell *execute* `subset.txt` (as if it were a command or script).

Answer (score 23):

You can pass a directory as a target to `grep` with `-R` and a file of input patterns with `-f`:

```
  -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
          multiple  times  or  is  combined with the -e (--regexp) option,
          search for all patterns given.  The  empty  file  contains  zero
          patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory,  recursively.   Follow  all
          symbolic links, unlike -r.
```

So, you're looking for:

```
grep -Ff subset.txt -r objects/
```

You can get the list of matching files with:

```
grep -Flf subset.txt -r objects/
```

So, if your final list isn't too long, you can just do:

```
 mv $(grep -Flf subset.txt -r objects/) new_dir/
```

If that returns an `argument list too long` error, use:

```
grep -Flf subset.txt -r objects/ | xargs -I{} mv {} bar/
```

And if your file names can contain spaces or other strange characters, use (assuming GNU `grep`):

```
grep -FZlf subset.txt -r objects/ | xargs -0I{} mv {} bar/
```

Finally, if you want to exclude binary files, use:

```
grep -IFZlf subset.txt -r objects/ | xargs -0I{} mv {} bar/
```

Comment: … or to avoid potentially thousands of `mv` invocation with one argument each: `... | xargs -0 mv -t bar/` (assuming your `mv` supports the `-t` option).

Answer (score 11):

use

```
grep -F -f subset.txt
```

to tell grep to read from `subset.txt` file.

you may use find to walk the file.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -F -f subset.txt {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec grep -F -f subset.txt {}  +
```

Comment: Any advantage of using `find` instead of `-r` other than that you do additional filtering?

Comment: @phk `grep -r` searches in symlinks to regular files, which may or may not be desirable (if they point inside the same tree, you're searching the same file twice; if they point outside, you're searching a file which may or may not be desired).

Comment: Modern versions of `grep` have options to control their interaction with symbolic links (`man grep` to determine the specifics for the current system).  A recursive `grep` will be a _lot_ faster than running `grep` individually on every file via `find`.

Comment: @Perry are you sure about that? Why? Also, note that this answer is using  `-exec +`, so it will group files and not run one grep per file.

Comment: I stand corrected, I was unaware of the different semantics of `-exec {} +` vs `-exec {} \;` ... you learn something new every day (I still see no reason why a single recursive `grep` wont be faster than multiple `grep`s run from `find` due to process creation and pattern parsing overhead but I don't have specific numbers to hand to back that up).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to speed up grep even more, you can set the locale in your shell before running it, i.e. use "LC_ALL=c".  This will be inherited into grep and will disable Unicode processing when not necessary and in some cases can dramatically speed up grep.  A great blog documenting this can be found at http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssh/speed-up-grep-searches-with-lc-all.  This trick also can speed up bash shell scripts as well, not just grep.