# How can we find all the files under a directory whose contents contain any of several strings?

Tags: awk, files, grep, find

I was wondering how to find all the files under a directory whose contents contain any of several strings  `word1`, `word2`, `word3`, ...?
Thanks.

Comment: you can do cd directory ; grep -rEl "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" depending on your needs it can just do the job. works fine with gnugrep

Comment: There are many duplicates of that question here.

Comment: @Stéphane I was looking for them too; funnily enough your own answer to [one of Tim’s questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58569/86440) fits the bill ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep`’s recursive search with multiple patterns:

```
grep -r -F -e word1 -e word2 -e word3
```

If you have many words to search for, store them in a file, one per line, and give that to `grep`:

```
grep -r -F -f patternfile
```

Add `-l` in both cases if you’re only interested in the files’ names, `-R` (instead of `-r`) if you want to dereference symlinks as you go down directory tree.

[How to grep thousands of files in a directory for hundreds of strings in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333561/86440) has tips for doing this over large numbers of files with large numbers of patterns.

Comment: doing this way can make huge output when many patterns appear in many files on many lines each ... add -l option will only display the filenames to avoid that :)

Comment: Thanks. What does -F mean here?

Comment: Which one is better, your command using `-e`, or `grep -rEl "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" `?

Comment: `-F` tells `grep` to treat the patterns as fixed strings rather than regular expressions. It is often significantly faster to use this; in my tests, searching for two patterns in 36,088 files occupying 6.3GiB (all in cache), the `grep -rFl -e ...` variant is 10× faster than the `grep -rEl ...` variant.